# Dynamically add dropshadow effect to Silverlight border?

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-behind

I would like to dynamically add a DropShadowEffect to my Silverlight border but cant figure out the C# syntax...

```
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Background="{StaticResource PanelBackground}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PanelBorderBrush}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Margin="0,8,0,0"
                        Width="250">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect />
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
```

I can create the border fine its the Border.Effect I am having trouble with.

Paul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect dropShadowEffect = new System.Windows.Media.Effects.DropShadowEffect();
dropShadowEffect.Opacity = 0.25;
dropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 5;
dropShadowEffect.BlurRadius = 10;
dropShadowEffect.Color = Colors.Black;
this.image.Effect = dropShadowEffect;
```

source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx

and

```
<Border Name="border">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>

    this.border.Effect = dropShadowEffect;
```